# Text autocomplete not working for Jupyter imports of personal package

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-packaging

I've made a package, put it in a private github repo, installed it locally via

```
pip install --upgrade git+[github url]
```

And when I try to run tab autocomplete in a jupyter notebook, it does not pull up what I'm searching for. The installation seems fine because if I type out the import the way I expect it, I can import the package and use it fine. Just the autocomplete isn't working. Is there a step I'm missing in the creation of a package that allows Jupyter to autocomplete it? I just made a basic setup.py file that defined the name, version, and package like this:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name=name,
    version='0.1',
    packages = [package1, package2, package3],
)
```

I'm on python 3.6 and I didn't make the __init__.py files since I read it wasn't necessary, not sure if those are necessary for jupyter however.

I've already tried restarting the kernel and restarting the server, no luck there.

**Small update**: I managed to get some autocomplete if I include an __init__.py file in one of the subpackages, but I still don't have autocomplete for the top level. Going to keep experimenting with this.

Answer (score 0):

I Think I figured it out. Adding the __init__.py files at all levels, even if it was empty, seemed to help and I needed to give Jupyter some time to I guess rebuild whatever cache is underneath storing the paths (there was always a delay in when autocomplete would kick in so I'm not sure what is happening but just being patient helps).